# ReactJS and ChartJS custom component

Tags: reactjs, charts, chart.js

I know my requirement is hard but I have a task for custom chart component (ReactJS) be like picture under. This is require from my company, I use ChartJS (4.0) and ReactJs for this project.

[image]

This is my link `codesandbox` I use for demo:
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/chartjs-bar-mkl8ys

My problem is require very difficulty, but I don't think we can custom chart like picture from their requirement. As you see, I need `header` and `footer` component abobe and under chart view.
Each column is 1 item data include label in right of column (ex: 0.8%, 0.2%...)

If you know how to custom like this, please help or give me a guide, thanks alot for your help.

Comment: You should use [chartjs plugin annotation](https://www.chartjs.org/chartjs-plugin-annotation/latest/guide/) and possibly also [chartjs plugin datalabels](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/). Get familiar with these and try to implement the required features of your chart. Then, if you get stuck, come back with specific questions that could be answered here on SO.